# Capturing events targeted to a child in parent component - iOS Cocoa Touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, events, event-handling

Is it possible in iOS to capture an event that is targeted to a child component in the parent component? Something similar to the event capturing phase in the DOM event model.

I'm trying to hide the keyboard when the user taps outside of the keyboard. I added an event handler that does that to the main view. It generally works fine, however, if the element tapped contains its own event handler, the event handler assigned to the main view isn't executed, because the event is already handled by the tapped component.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

You either want to add a transparent view, which will receive the events, over your whole layout when displaying the keyboard or override `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` in all your components and return NO when the keyboard is displayed

Comment: I don't like the 2nd option, but the first one seems promising. I just have one question. I still want the handler on the child component to be executed when the user taps the screen and the keyboard hides. Won't the transparent view receive all events and they won't be propagated to the children? I don't want the users to tap twice, first to hide the keyboard, then to execute the component's action.

Comment: Try setting `cancelsTouchesInView` to NO on your gesture recognizer for the transparent view. If that doesn't work, override `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch`. Inside it, detect if the touch hits a subview with an action (ie a button,...) and then dismiss the keyboard and return NO.